# How to receive emails from Azure B2C users ending with x.onmicrosoft.com

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I need to click the activation links in our Azure B2C accounts which end with  **x.onmicrosoft.com**.

How can I accomplish that?

Should we set up an email server or is there a more practical way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Do you mean you are wanting to send activation links out from your B2C tenant to users to sign themselves up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, basically. onmicrosoft.com is the parent domain owned by Microsoft and the do not allow you to specify the required DNS changes that would allow you to setup a mail server for say joeblogs.onmicrosoft.com. You need to either collect valid email addresses at registration time or disable email activation.